# In watir, is there a way to capture the text matched by .present?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

It is possible to only get the text that was matched by a call to .present?

The specific issue was that the page contains a string of the form "TIME: ##:##" where # is [0-9].  I'm interested in the value of ##:##

I can solve the specific problem with something like (hopefully no typos)

```
myString = "TIME: [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"
myRegExp = /#{myString.gsub(/\s/, '\s')}/
if ( @browser.div(:text => myRegExp).present? )
    myResult = @browser.div(:text => myRegExp).text
end
```

In my test, myResult is a string containing all of the text elements on the page; which is more information than I want.  I want "TIME: ##:##"

Of course, I can use Ruby to get what I want

```
myResult [ myRegExp ]
```

The specific issue is solved.  The more general question is more of a best practices question.  Is there a better way?  Is there a way to get Watir to return just the part of the string that matched or is using the Ruby string class the best way to solve this sort of problem?

Comment: I tend to use Ruby to do any/all of the 'extra' stuff I want out of my tests. In terms of 'Best Practices' I would say just use 'Watir' for 'driving' the browser test. so in you particular case. I would save the full string then parse it later into the format you want.

Comment: @Carldmitch, thanks.  I'm asked because I did a similar thing a few years ago where I post-processed output from SQL using some PHP code.  I got grief because some of what I did in PHP was something that the SQL engine could have done.  Once bitten...  (The code I write is going to be reviewed by an independent auditor and I will need to defend whatever I did.  I'm trying to be careful.)

Comment: Is the string literally `TIME: [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]` on the page?  And are you trying to extract "the value of ##:##" or "TIME: ##:##"?

Comment: @Orde, I was trying to learn if Watir had a method that would give me just the characters that matched the regular expression.  Based on the comments thus far, it appears the answer is "no."

Comment: @Orde (part 2) To address your specific question, I eventually wanted to extract the data and store it in two variables, minutes and seconds.  Between the time I asked my question and now, I have accomplished that task.  -- In closing, 2 months ago, I never heard of Cucumber or Watir and had never written anything in Ruby.  The purpose of my question is to help me learn.  (Just because I fail to find something doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  I'm trying to learn what exists and what doesn't exist.)

Comment: @Carldmitch, IMHO your comment is the best answer.  If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @HughMcCurdy comment is now answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use Ruby to do any/all of the 'extra' stuff I want out of my tests. In terms of 'Best Practices' I would say just use 'Watir' for 'driving' the browser test. so in you particular case. I would save the full string then parse it later into the format you want.